# Menu icon toggle issue JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icons

I obtained a toggle control that animates between a menu icon and an `X` when clicked. It also presents an overlay nav.

**the problem is:** When you click any link on the overlay nav, it doesn't change/toggle `X` back to the default menu icon.

---

In the following code snippet, I added `$('.cd-menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked'); $('.cd-header').toggleClass('menu-is-open');` (on lines 33, 34) to initially set the toggled state of the control.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //if you change this breakpoint in the style.css file (or _layout.scss if you use SASS), don't forget to update this value as well
    var MQL = 1170;

    //primary navigation slide-in effect
    if($(window).width() > MQL) {
        var headerHeight = $('.cd-header').height();
        $(window).on('scroll',
        {
            previousTop: 0
        }, function () {
            var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            //check if user is scrolling up
            if (currentTop < this.previousTop ) {
                //if scrolling up...
                if (currentTop > 0 && $('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
                    $('.cd-header').addClass('is-visible');
                } else {
                    $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
                }
            } else {
                //if scrolling down...
                $('.cd-header').removeClass('is-visible');
                if( currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.cd-header').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.cd-header').addClass('is-fixed');
            }
            this.previousTop = currentTop;
        });
    }

    //open/close primary navigation
    $('.cd-primary-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
        $('.cd-menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked');
        $('.cd-header').toggleClass('menu-is-open');

        //in firefox transitions break when parent overflow is changed, so we need to wait for the end of the trasition to give the body an overflow hidden
        if( $('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('is-visible') ) {
            $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
                $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
            });
        } else {
            $('.cd-primary-nav').addClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
                $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope someone can help.

---

To reproduce: (use **JsFiddle [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gps3yk7g/8/)**)

1. Open menu (click 'hamgburger' icon box area)
2. Click any link on the overlay, when it's presented. (i.e "1", "2", "3", "4")
3. Result: the overlay closes, but the menu icon doesn't toggle back.

Comment: I think in the fiddel specified, it is working correctly.

Comment: it isn't @Lal..
 the issue is minor: there isn't an eventListener on the links, nor overlay, that toggles the 'menu-is-open' class on '.cd-header'. The reason could be because the markup of that html is malformed.. please correct your html (particularly the div with no closing tag that is within the nav tag).

Comment: Sorry the html is partially cut out of a document as is the other code to go in a jsfiddle for just the menu part issue. However I will check my html for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have implemented the custom click events on `1, 2, 3, 4` links in `<script>` tag **(line 253)** in the HTML part.

Just replace that `<script>` tag with below:

```
<script>
  $('.cd-primary-nav a').on('click', function(){
  $('.cd-menu-icon').removeClass('is-clicked');
  $('.cd-header').removeClass('menu-is-open');
  $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
    $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
  });
  });
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c9dj010v/

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! This has fixed it! I implemented it a while ago in different parts and must have forgot this part. Thank you very much for solving this issue!

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is to add a new click listener that will listen to clicks on your links

```
$('.nav-overlay').click(function() {
    $('.cd-menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked');
});
```

In your original fiddle, the hamburger icon will only change when it is clicked directly because the click listener is attached only to that element

[Modified Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eeb7usd5/1/)

Comment: hmm... you are conceptually correct, but it seems you modified the code sample so much that you got some false positives that lead you  to providing an incorrect solution. `$('cd-header').toggleClass('menu-is-open')` is what actually toggles the control's animation/state..

Comment: your modification of the click event on the `$(document)` is actually what is causing your sample to function initially, but it breaks in about 2-3 tests.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, Ive fixed it from the post above.